# Why doesn't the count of '0' change on Search Results when i select some records or 'all on this page'

Tags: search-results

Am pasting as a question for others who might come across this but have reported on JIRA as it replicates on http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm

Do any search, then select eg first record, or the checkbox above the first one to get 'all on this page' - and the count of '0' stays same, and hence you can't select any Actions.

Comment: If you select multiple contacts selecting them one by one it does change, the only select checkbook that doesn't change/work is the '__Select all rows/ All on this page__', the one above the first contact in the result.

Comment: Apologies, spelling corrector, I meant __checkbox__ not checkbook.

Comment: hmm - maybe - i definitely had it with a single tick, and a zero, but now all i can manage is having it show 2 when i only have a single box ticked, but that was after selecting all, unselecting, etc and general messing around. Seems my jira was a duplicate and original ticket is at https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18521

Answer (score 2):

A bug had already been filed on [JIRA](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18521) and it is listed as FIXED for 4.6.17